# How do I re-enable the Tags part of Tags and Notes in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, tags

We have enabled Tags on the server and we see the option for Note Board but we do not have the option for Tags. Our production server should be set up the same as our development server yet on the production server we have the Tags tab listed in Tags and Notes. We are using SharePoint 2013 (not online) on Server 2012 R2.
All the links I have come across are to enable BOTH the Tags and Notes section. We already have that section enabled but for some reason we cannot see the Tags part and only see the Note Board.

[image: This is a picture of what we see]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to check for tags part.

- Make sure you have Managed Metadata service provisioned in your farm
- Make sure Managed Metadata service is connected with the web applicaton. `Central admin > application management > manage web application > highlight the web application then click on Service Connection in Ribbon`. in pop up make sure MMS connected.
- Also from UPA make sure user has permission for tags and notes.Go to `Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage service applications -> User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Permissions -> make sure you have enabled "Use Tags and Notes" for All Authenticated Users.`
- If above are in place, lastly check if you can browse Managed Metadata service in Central admin. may be recycle the app pool for the MMS service application.

Comment: Yep that was it, our Managed Metadata Service is only running on Prod not Dev. I don't know if this will resolve the whole issue but I have a feeling it will. There are a list of other services that are running in Prod and not Dev as well so we will be sure to fix that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also used these links to enable the Managed Metadata Service.

Comment: https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/02/step-by-step-guide-to-configure-the-managed-metadata-service-application-for-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12713.sharepoint-2013-how-to-configure-managed-metadata-service.aspx